# text:maxLines and text:ellipsize not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to limit my TextView to 2 lines. Here's my layout XML, the TextView in question is the id/description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OBJEKTBESCHREIBUNG"
    android:textAppearance="@style/LargeText"
    android:textColor="@color/myorange" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/myorange" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textAppearance="@style/StandardText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mehr ..."
    android:textAppearance="@style/SmallText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The text is ellipsized where it should (see picture), but the next word ist still visible.

What's causing this?

Edit: This is the text style that I set to the TextView:

```
<style name="StandardText">
    <item name="android:fontFamily" tools:ignore="NewApi">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Edit2: Tried removing the textAppearance attribute, but it had no effect (concerning the ellipsize 'bug').

[image]

Comment: Are you setting any Typeface font style in your code?

Comment: What if the text is large?

Comment: @Sri Yes I do, I added the style to my question.

Comment: Yea that's the problem dude...Actually i have faced the same problem in my last project...Just removed the that style and check, it will work correctly i hope...The problem is, your customized typeface may not support the ellipsize feature properly...

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it without the textAppearance, but the bug remains :(

Comment: What's the exact text that causes this problem?  From your screenshot it looks like there are some ligatures, which seem like exactly the sort of thing that would throw off the calculations used to decide where to put ellipses.

Comment: @blahdiblah The text in the screenshot is styled with <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item> but the bug also happens when using the default text style.

Comment: @Ascorbin 1- Can you give us the complete text? 2- Can you try english characters only?

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib It's all kind of texts coming from an API, just tested removing the german 'umlauts' but it didn't help.

Comment: A@Ascorbin I am checking the source code. Can you try to explicitly specify Gravity?

Comment: Tried setting android:gravity="left" in the TextView but that didn't change anything. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem appears when your input text contains a newline or some other "special" character exactly in the area that should be ellipsized.

Try using:

```
text.replaceAll("(\\t|\\r?\\n)", " ")
```

this might fix your problem.

Comment: I tried it, to no avail. The bug happens with all kinds of Strings that don't contain special chars.

Comment: That solved the same issue for me, you should by the way add also padding to the sides.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OBJEKTBESCHREIBUNG"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="demotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotext"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Mehr ..."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is not a good example: you should add some spaces (words) to the text.

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that `fontFamily` doesn't work with the combination `maxLines` and `ellipsize`.
In my case, I had to remove the `ellipsize`.